# Javascript setter function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating a class function in js like the following to create new Google Maps.

I have a problem having a default value for zoom variable and be able to change it after the object has been created.

Here is a piece of code of the function:

```
function GMap(lat,lng){
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = lng;
    this.mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    this.map = null;
    this.zoom = 20; // As a default value

    this.setZoom = function(value)
    {
        this.zoom = value;
    }   
    this.getZoom = function()
    {
        return this.zoom;
    }   
    this.mapOptions = {
        center: this.mapCenter,
        zoom: this.zoom
    };
    this.createMap = function(htmlElement)
    {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(htmlElement), this.mapOptions);
        return this.map;
    }  
}
```

I am calling the above like this:

```
var gMap= new GMap(10, 20);     
gMap.setZoom(9); 
console.log(gMap.getZoom()); //Returns 9 successfully

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', gMap.createMap('mapDiv')); //but creates a map with default zoom 20
```

Comment: What is `GoogleMap`?

Comment: Dynamically create `this.mapOptions` by current value when you need it, in your current code, the value is set upon create, set `this.zoom` will not change its value. So `this.mapOptions.zoom` will always be `20` no matter that you set `this.zoom` to `9`.

Comment: You're executing `gMap.createMap('mapDiv')` right away, and the result is passed as callback. The callback should be a function: `....addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){ gMap.createMap('mapDiv') });`

Comment: Thank you very much @fuyushimoya your answer helped me fix my problem !

Answer (score -2):

You have functions to set or get properties of map.
I think with this functions you can modify the zoom property.
I hope this be useful for you.

[Google Maps Documentation V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)